# error on getAttribute while parsing an xml document in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

I'm calling a webservice from javascript and then parsing the xml and rendering tables. All is well in firefox, but in IE its a different story.

The problem seems to be on this this line

```
var count = result.childNodes[0].getAttribute('Count');
```

Is there an IE friendly way to get an xml attribute in javascript?

the rest of the code works fine. but unfortunately i need that count.

Comment: Did you know there are more than one version of IE?  Tell us which one you are referring to.

Comment: getAttribute works fine for XML documents in IE (there are issues with HTML documents). There's no error in the posted snippet; we need to see more code.

Answer (score 1):

This works in IE 7:

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0].attributes;
document.write(x.getNamedItem("category").nodeValue);
```

**book** is your element name and **category** is the name of the attribute. I found this example on W3Schools:

- Tutorial:
  http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/dom_nodes_nodelist.asp
- Example:
  http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_attributes
- XML:
  http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/books.xml